# how to retreive last number in the data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

this is my data in the database and i'm using mysql
[database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bq8NY.png)

How do I retreive number "4" from the data using sql command?

Comment: It would be much easier to retrieve the data then filter at the application level.

Comment: i have a table name "client" and column name "client_ic". the data inside column client_ic are '1234' and '941124'.I want to retreive the number '4' from the last data inside the column

Answer (score 0):

USE reverse and left

```
set @myfield = 1234;
select left(reverse(@myfield),1) as result;
```

---

```
result
4
```

demo here
http://rextester.com/LTBE34983

Comment: it return null sir.